# Regex to match only when a term in present later in string

Tags: php, regex

I have some text in the following format:

```
Name Andy Andyson
Address Line 1 43 Main Street
Address Line 2 Bigtown
Case Ref 23652/54362
Office
Address Line 1 1 Main Street
Address Line 2 Bigtown
App Date 12/01/2008
```

I am trying to extract the first Address Line 1. I am using the regex in PHP:

```
/Address Line 1 ([A-Za-z0-9 ]{1,25})/
```

which works great unless the first address is not present (or the row text is `Address Une 1` for example), in which case it might return the second Address Line 1.

How can I force the regex to only return `Address Line 1` if it is followed by `Office` at some later point?

I have tried using lookaheads:

```
Address Line 1 ([A-Za-z0-9 ]{1,30})(?=.*Office)
Address Line 1 ([A-Za-z0-9 ]{1,30})(?=.*\n\rOffice)
Address Line 1 ([A-Za-z0-9 ]{1,30})(?!.*\n\rOffice)
Address Line 1 ([A-Za-z0-9 ]{1,30}).*Office
```

I think lookaheads is how to confirm a later value is present in the string, but none of the above work.

If it can't find a match for the first `Address 1` before the word `Office` then I just want it to return nothing, not the second `Address 1` val.

The following should produce **no** matches, whereas currently it returns `1 Main Street`:

```
Name Andy Andyson
Address Une 1 43 Main Street
Address Line 2 Bigtown
Case Ref 23652/54362
Office
Address Line 1 1 Main Street
Address Line 2 Bigtown
App Date 12/01/2008
```

Comment: Did you use `preg_match` or `preg_match_all`? Look at [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/Irntsj/1), your regex is OK to use with `preg_match`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Sorry, `preg_match`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Hmm no that doesn't work, it still returns the second Address Line 1... Try the second example text I gave.

Comment: But it is still the first occurrence of `Address Line 1`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Sorry for confusion - As it says in q: "How can I force the regex to only return Address Line 1 if it is followed by Office at some later point?"

Comment: Then use `/Address Line 1 ([A-Za-z0-9 ]{1,30})(?=.*\ROffice)/s`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first attempt (`Address Line 1 ([A-Za-z0-9 ]{1,30})(?=.*Office)`) is OK but you need to make `.` match newlines by using the singleline modifier. For example, you may set it in-line (notice the `(?s)`):

```
(?s)Address Line 1 ([A-Za-z0-9 ]{1,30})(?=.*Office)
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/R0YZRV/1

Or place it after the closing regex bracket:

```
preg_match('/Address Line 1 ([A-Za-z0-9 ]{1,30})(?=.*Office)/s', $input, $matches);
                                                             ^
                                               Notice this --'
```

Demo: https://ideone.com/Bv3tvL

**P.S.**

Although not stated explicitly, you may need that `Office` to be alone on a line. In this case it should be surrounded by `^` (start of line) and `$` (end of line) and the `/m` modifier should be used:

```
preg_match('/Address Line 1 ([A-Za-z0-9 ]{1,30})(?=.*^Office$)/sm', $input, $matches);
```

Demo: https://ideone.com/1pNGNY

Comment: Just in PHP, using `/pattern/s` is more natural than `/(?s)pattern/`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: yes, you're right. I was just preparing am IdeOne demo...

Comment: The `(?=.*Office)` will assure the presence of `Office` anywhere in the text after the current position. If the word must be found at the beginning of a line, and be equal to the whole line, a `/Address Line 1 ([A-Za-z0-9 ]{1,30})(?=.*^Office$)/sm` could be more precise.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: Good point. This can be inferred from the question despite the explicit requirement was only _"followed by Office at some later point"_. I'll add it to the answer. Thank you.

Comment: Anyway, I believe the main issue was the missing `/s`.